# Non-linear Shape Key without key frames

Tags: shape-keys

I want to make data-driven facial animation based on FACS (Facial Action Coding System). I know that you can set a Shape Key to for example create a smile, however, as far as I understand, the model changes in a linear fashion from base model to the morph target. The deformation of a human face however happens in a non-linear fashion. Some wrinkles of a smile only appear when you stretch your mouth to the maximum. It would be weird that wrinkles already slightly appear when the Shape Key value is `0.1`.

One way to create this effect is by setting key frames, but then it becomes an animation. My data, however, comes from facial motion capture. I still want to be able to export the model to e.g. Unity 3D, where I assign a value between 0 and 1 to every shape key for the desired facial expression.

Is there a way to have 1 Shape Key to have 2 or more target morphs? E.g. between values `0.0`-`0.2` it targets morph 1, between `0.2`-`0.7` morph 2, and between `0.7`-`1.0` morph 3. Or another way to achieve the above described effect without animation (that can be exported)?